# How to navigate google search results in Safari 8 with keyboard?

Tags: safari, google, search-engine

A while ago I remember being able to navigate through search results using J and K.

Is there anyway to do that in Safari 8?

I've tried changing tab behaviour in Safari prefs to tab through every item, but that's too many tabs to accomplish what I want to do.

Comment: I think you can look into Google's keyboard shortcut list or try in some other browsers to see if Safari is the cause.

Comment: I tried with google chrome, no luck there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extension that will let you do it in Google Chrome: https://github.com/nqzero/knogs

At the bottom of that page is a link to do the same thing in Safari (I can't link to it directly from here because I don't have the reputation for it).

I haven't tried either version though.

Personally, I use Mafuyu (http://wakabamac.blog95.fc2.com/blog-entry-1013.html). Instead of using `J` and `K` to navigate and `return` to open the result, you use `1`-`9` or `0` to open the result directly.